# Add values in lambda template.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on a set of API's using the SAM framework and was wondering if there is a way to specify additional values in `template.yaml` that I could retrieve in my lambda handler?

Ideally, I would have something like this in `template.yaml`:

```
PostExperiment:
     Type: Api
     Properties:
         Path: /my-path
         Method: post
         Metadata:
           value1: "software"
```

And then in my lambda handler, I could access it something like:

```
export async function lambdaHandler(event, context) {
   // get `value1` from `event` or `context` somehow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Environment Variables that can be retrieved like any other env variable depending on your language ( os.env in python for instance )

See this [aws-sam-local environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104665/aws-sam-local-environment-variables)