# Refer outside variables in AWS SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I am using AWS SAM for creating some infrastructures. In the below-mentioned template, the role of the state machine is hard coded. Here, say if I want to refer this from another file say config.json. How can I achieve it.?

```
Resources:
  OcxDataLoadMachine:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      Name: ocx_data_load_scripts_machine
      DefinitionUri: ./stepfunctions/ocx_data_load_scripts_machine.asl.json
      Role: "arn:aws:iam::875221978636:role/service-role/StepFunctions-postgres_fact_data_load-role-0f4a24d5"
```

In serverless model these data we referred data using :

```
${file(./config.json):IAMROLE}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of config.json you can use the samconfig.toml for referring those values. The config can also be overidden with -config-file parameter.

Check the below link for more details.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html

Comment: I plan to maintain names of IAM roles on the file for many resources. How can we refer the value from samconfig.toml into the template.yaml file. Can you share snippet.

Comment: You can use the parameters and then use the parameter references. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104665/aws-sam-local-environment-variables

Comment: version=0.1
[default.global.parameters]
parameter_overrides=[
  "TemplateInput1=Value1",
  "TemplateInput2=Value2"
]